# Como eu faço um pull do repositório remoto do gitlab em uma pipeline freestyle do jenkins?

Tags: amazon-aws, jenkins, pipeline

gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de buscar atualizações de repositórios remotos, fazendo um git pull, com uma pipeline fresstyle do jenkins. Eu estou usando o jenkins apenas para buscar atualizações nas branchs master e developer. Eu criei um job e passei esse script

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso reiniciar o pm2, e executar o yarn (para o caso de eu ter adicionado uma lib nova) Porém estou recendo erro de permissão negada, quando o jenkins tenta fazer um pull

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu seu que o meu acesso com o gitlab, por ssh está correto, pois o agente do jenkins faz o pull dentro da pasta workspaces. Eu não sei se a forma mais correta seria copiar ou mover o código de dentro dessa pasta, ou redirecionar o local que ele faz o pull padrão. Estou usando ec2 da aws diferentes, um para o jenkins e outro para homologação e produção

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Não vale a pena você usar os hooks do Gitlab pra notificar o Jenkins quando esses branches forem atualizados?

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html